# Amazon Workspaces - Audit

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is it possible to record [Amazon Workspaces](http://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/) for audit purpose? I think that it's a common uses case but I couldn't find any documentation nor other solutions.  Basically I would like to review the client activity by recording its screen 24/7 and perhaps store the recordings on S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing baked into any Amazon Web Services offering that does this.

But, with that being said, the Amazon Workspace is just a Windows Server 2008R2 server with desktop experience installed.

You could of course install 3rd party software to do this for you, in terms of pushing to S3 you could use TNTDrive to mount an S3 bucket as a thumbdrive, and push your logs that way..

Answer (score 0):

As of today there isn't any explicit way of logging / monitoring / recording the activity for Amazon Workspaces. One of Workspaces cousins Zocalo [ Document Collaboration and Storage ] had logging out of the box - like "Who created which document from where at what time".

To start with - if you integrate your AD [Using On Prem AD / AD Connector / SimpleAD ] and Amazon Workspaces to authenticate the users - you can get the advantage of same credentials / access policy / audit policy which is been used in your Corporate AD so long.

This is currently the only possible way you can enable audit for Workspace, I can think of. Given that Workspaces is a aimed towards the enterprises, with auditing & compliance playing a vital role; we can certainly expect that Amazon would working on one.

Answer (score 0):

You can now log user activity using Cloudtrail: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/amazon-workspaces-monitoring.html It's not quite the same thing as capturing screen shots, but it might get you the information you need.